# How can I abort Pepper speech via Tablet touchscreen?

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I would like to interrupt Pepper's TextToSpeech service while it speaks by using Pepper Tablet application?

What is the method I need to call to terminate it's speech?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALTextToSpeech API offers the function [stopAll()](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-api.html?highlight=stopall#ALTextToSpeechProxy::stopAll)

To utilize the Pepper Tablet Application, you could make a javascript call to a function like:

```
function stopTalking() {
    QiSession(function (session) {
        session.service("ALTextToSpeech").then(function (tts) {
            tts.stopAll()
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("An error occurred:", error)
        })
    })
}
```